# How to get the correct shape position

Tags: createjs

```
shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill('#000').drawCircle(100, 0, 6);
shape.x = 100;
shape.y = 100;
stage.addChild(shape);
stage.update();
```

When I use this code, the shape is placed at the point(200,100). Why is it not placed at point(100,100) instead?

Comment: Circles are drawn from the center.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean "the shape is placed at the point (200, 100) ?".
Actually, the drawing is made according to the top left corner of the shape.
Your shape is certainly drawn in (100, 100) but as the circle diameter is 100px, it will be drawn from the point (100, 100) to the point (200, 200).